# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#

Помогите, плиз. 
Когда запускаю прогу, у меня проверяет обнову:

```
        File.Delete("Ver.txt");
        File.Delete("WF_SigScanner.exe");
        if (File.Exists("ver.txt"))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            File.AppendAllText("ver.txt", "1");
        }

        WebClient vers = new WebClient();
        string vers1 = vers.DownloadString("http://egor2323.hol.es/всё/ver.txt");
        string verc1 = File.ReadAllText("ver.txt");
        if (verc1 != vers1)
        {
            //     Process.Start("name.exe");
        }
        else
        {
            button4.Text = "нет обнов";
            //     Process.Start("name.exe");
        }
```

И если нет обновы, сразу пишет:
Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

На коде button4.Text = "нет обнов";

Comment: Может быть, у вас нет button4?)

Comment: Да, я тоже сначала подумал, но есть.

Comment: Вот скрин http://img.chitachok.ru/image.uploads/21-09-2014/original-153f0b9cfdc4359701593b22ec9e9476.jpg

Comment: @ЕгорГлухов, ссылка не работает даже с включенным VPN

Comment: @CasperSC Сайта давно перестроен, Я даже не помню, что там было, и из за чего ошибка)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к кнопке до инициализации формы, добавьте проверку, на событие загрузки формы, либо в конструкторе, но после InitializeComponent();

Comment: Спасибо большое, все теперь работает.